# how to create JSON array [] for REST response?

Tags: rest-api, api, json

I am trying to create a REST response for a self-developed API in WordPress. The current code is

```
    $response = array();

    $response[] = array(
        'version' => '1.0',
        'user' => array(
            'first_name' => $user->first_name,
            'last_name' => $user->last_name,
            'email' => $user->user_email,
            'id' => $user->ID,
        ),
    );

return rest_ensure_response( $response );
```

Which returns (i am using a user object)

```
[
{
"version": "1.0",
"user": {
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "User",
    "email": "test@test.xyz",
    "id": 19
}
}
]
```

However i need it in this form

```
[
  {
"version": "1.0",
"user": [
    {
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "User",
        "email": "stather@auktionen-in-heidelberg.de",
        "id": 19,
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

So the challenge here is how to get the [] around the "user"?

This is more likely a general questions as im unable to add the "[" and "]" manually to the response array

Best, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Just use another `array()` inside user `array()`

```
$response = array();

$response[] = array(
    'version' => '1.0',
    'user' => array(
        array(
            'first_name' => 'Razon',
            'last_name' => 'komar pal',
            'email' => 'razonkumar@gmail.com',
            'id' => 10,
        )
    ),
);

return rest_ensure_response($response);
```

It will output like:

```
[
    {
        "version": "1.0",
        "user": [
            {
                "first_name": "Razon",
                "last_name": "komar pal",
                "email": "razonkumar@gmail.com",
                "id": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Hope this will work for you :)